# How to update fastlane with Fabric app

Tags: crashlytics, fastlane, google-fabric

Using fastlane in the console, it tells me, that there is an update available and I should update using the App.

`fastlane 2.27.0 is available. You are on 2.25.0.
 It is recommended to use the latest version.
 Please update using the Fabric app. Launch the app and navigate to the 
 fastlane tab to get the most recent version..`

But I don't see any possibility to update.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If you don't see the update button present, try quitting and relaunching Fabric.app to force a check for an update. Once that's done, you should see the option to update below the Fastlane logo.

[image]

Comment: not for me.
"fastlane 2.60.0 is available. You are on 2.59.0."
fabric 2.6.14
fastlane 2.59.0

Comment: Sorry if I'm not following, but that sounds like you're being prompted to upgrade.